# CSS gradient striping in Chrome

Tags: css, gradient

I used the Colorzilla CSS gradient generator to create a background that has multiple color stops. It works great in Firefox and Safari but in Chrome there is a subtle striping/banding thing going on that is frustrating. Here's my code and a jsfiddle link:

```
body {
background: rgb(0,0,0); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(85,187,0,1) 15%, rgba(85,187,0,1) 25%, rgba(221,34,85,1) 45%, rgba(221,34,85,1) 55%, rgba(0,136,238,1) 75%, rgba(0,136,238,1) 85%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(15%,rgba(85,187,0,1)), color-stop(25%,rgba(85,187,0,1)), color-stop(45%,rgba(221,34,85,1)), color-stop(55%,rgba(221,34,85,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(0,136,238,1)), color-stop(85%,rgba(0,136,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(85,187,0,1) 15%,rgba(85,187,0,1) 25%,rgba(221,34,85,1) 45%,rgba(221,34,85,1) 55%,rgba(0,136,238,1) 75%,rgba(0,136,238,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(85,187,0,1) 15%,rgba(85,187,0,1) 25%,rgba(221,34,85,1) 45%,rgba(221,34,85,1) 55%,rgba(0,136,238,1) 75%,rgba(0,136,238,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(85,187,0,1) 15%,rgba(85,187,0,1) 25%,rgba(221,34,85,1) 45%,rgba(221,34,85,1) 55%,rgba(0,136,238,1) 75%,rgba(0,136,238,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(85,187,0,1) 15%,rgba(85,187,0,1) 25%,rgba(221,34,85,1) 45%,rgba(221,34,85,1) 55%,rgba(0,136,238,1) 75%,rgba(0,136,238,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
width:100%;
margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yL82a/
(ignore the margin-bottom declaration)

Any idea how to fix this in Chrome to just be a nice smooth gradient? I've tried this using both rgba and hex values and get the same result.

Comment: I don't see any difference between firefox and chrome, OH now I see, fainted opaque strips

Comment: For me it looks the same in Chrome and Firefox, both have quite visible bands. Here's a screenshot from my end, Firefox: http://i.imgur.com/1KwImIF.png

Comment: Thanks @moettinger -- seems like that's my answer. If you want to, you can leave your response as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to do with how Chrome handles dithering. Issue was discussed here:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8426/gradient-banding-in-chrome

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the whole page to have a gradient background, and this issue was quite annoying.
At the end I could remove the stripes by applying `-webkit-filter: blur(3px);` to `<body>`, but then the whole content was blurred, so I made a separate`<div>` to be the background of the page, and applied the filter to that.

CSS:

```
html, body {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}

#page-background
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #383838; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #383838 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    (...)
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="page-background"></div>
    And content goes here...
```

Gradient was generated at [ColorZilla site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Answer (score -1):

try to generate css gradient  from this site, and see if any difference you can found, it will help you to debug your code,

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

Best of Luck..

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it just may be the way Chrome handles gradients, as that tool yields the same result.